# Wordpress Blogroll CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

The questions is related to wordpress blogroll CSS

I did setup a blogroll with thumbnail as illustrated in the screenshot. But blogroll looks ugly if it has more characters in it. How can i setup the blogroll as illustrated in the screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlkXA.gif

Setting up this blogroll in http://www.onepriceindia.in

I did not know much about CSS. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: can you please post link of the page instead?

Comment: http://www.onepriceindia.co.in/nokia-c1-02-mobile-phone-specifications-price-in-india/

Answer (score 0):

```
.widget .blogroll a img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 15px 10px !important;
}

.widget .blogroll li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    min-height: 85px;
}
```

have tested it on your blog... this is quickest way!

Comment: I have applied the CSS, Unfortunately the CSS is not working.

Comment: can u give link to the page on which this is happening?

Comment: Hello tarun, here it is http://www.onepriceindia.co.in/nokia-c1-02-mobile-phone-specifications-price-in-india/

Comment: The suggested CSS breaks sidebar and looks awkward. Look it please

Comment: http://www.onepriceindia.co.in/nokia-x3-02-touch-type-mobile-phone-price-in-india/

Comment: Test the link in google chrome, all the images are magnified.